# How can I reset a sequence's value to 1 for every new year in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using the sequence to generate an identifier in the format YYYY-"sequence value" and the sequence value has to be reset to 1 for every new year. for example: for this year's value will be like 2011-3456. when new year comes, it should be set to like: 2012-0001.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do - or what you mean by the sequence value being reset... what would you expect to know about the current time? (I would normally inject a clock as a dependency.)

Comment: You should state what you get with what you've done, and what differs from what you want to do. THEN, we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution, assuming you want an identifier for each year and its yearly day:

```
private string GetYearlyIdentifier(DateTime date)
{
  return String.Format("{0:0000}-{0:000}",date.Year, date.DayOfYear);
}
```

(Not Tested)